# Grouping different column on similar record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple query that pulls three fields:  ID, lab, and procedure.

Instead of the query showing two rows when the ID and lab are the same but the procedure is different,

(ex ID: 1, Lab: blood, procedure: physical ; ID: 1, lab: blood, procedure: eye exam)

how can i get it to group so that when there is a similar ID and lab, the results are only one record with multiple procedure columns?

(ex ID: 1, Lab: blood, procedure 1: physical, procedure 2: eye exam)

Here is my query

```
SELECT
  pe.ID 
 ,l.acttextdisplay as Lab
 ,pp.service_item_desc as Procedure
FROM lab l
JOIN patient_encounter pe ON l.ID = pe.ID
JOIN patient_procedure pp ON pp.ID = pe.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use group_concat

```
SELECT
  pe.ID 
 ,l.acttextdisplay as Lab
 , group_concat(pp.service_item_desc)  as Procedure
FROM lab l
JOIN patient_encounter pe ON l.ID = pe.ID
JOIN patient_procedure pp ON pp.ID = pe.ID
group by  pe.ID ,l.acttextdisplay
```

in this way you obtain a sinle for for id, lab with all the procedure in the same

in sqlserver you could use

```
 STRING_AGG(pp.service_item_desc, ',')
```

Comment: this would be exactly what im looking for but only have access to SSMS 2016 and neither group_concat or string_agg are recognized on there

Comment: @zdsnide   . your question is tagged mysql  ..so the answer  if ro mysql

Answer (score -1):

You can use `group by` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT pe.ID 
       MAX(CASE WHEN pp.service_item_desc THEN 'blood' THEN l.acttextdisplay END) as blood,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pp.service_item_desc THEN 'eye' THEN l.acttextdisplay END) as eye,
       . . .
FROM lab l JOIN
     patient_encounter pe
     ON l.ID = pe.ID JOIN
     patient_procedure pp
     ON pp.ID = pe.ID
GROUP BY pe.ID
```